# jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I can't get it to do anything. The drop down just behaves normally. I've followed their instructions and created the simplest demo I could and still nothing works. I've checked my paths and put everything in the same directory to make sure everything is being found. I have jQuery being loaded first.

Here's the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Searchable</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.src.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select").searchable();
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="0">Aardvark</option>
    <option value="1">Beta</option>
    <option value="2">Charlie</option>
    <option value="3">Louis Chan</option>
    <option value="4">Zoomba</option>
    <option value="5">Lima</option>
</select>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a link to the plugin. Demo is on the plugin page: http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am not familiar with this plugin. Can you link to the library and ideally provide a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: it's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/Bj2dS/
just make sure your scripts are loading correctly and that you have o errors in your console
I used this script http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/jquery.searchabledropdown.js

Comment: $.browser is removed [link](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the code and tested it. The problem is jQuery 1.9.1, when I put that version it does not work, but when I put back jQuery 1.8.3 it works.
I don't think there is a way to solve it unless you dig in the library, so it's better to use 1.8.3 as in the demo.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Searchable</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net//jquery.searchabledropdown.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select").searchable();
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="0">Aardvark</option>
    <option value="1">Beta</option>
    <option value="2">Charlie</option>
    <option value="3">Louis Chan</option>
    <option value="4">Zoomba</option>
    <option value="5">Lima</option>
</select>  
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like the $.browser has been removed from jquery 1.9 core and above see the reference [here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) you can decide to fix the problem by changing the library, use an older jquery version or use another alternative [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/) you can find some better examples.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the above Example: Once you searched the key like **'Zoo..'** then you can select **'Zoomba'**. Again If want to **change the selection**, in that list you can **able to see only 'Zoomba'** not all values.

If you want to show all values in that list you have to clear that searched key once **selected index changed**. Like this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Searchable</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net//jquery.searchabledropdown.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myselect').searchable();

      $('#myselect').change(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="myselect">
    <option value="0">Aardvark</option>
    <option value="1">Beta</option>
    <option value="2">Charlie</option>
    <option value="3">Louis Chan</option>
    <option value="4">Zoomba</option>
    <option value="5">Lima</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You written code is fine, It is a browser and Jquery version related issue.

1. Runs on IE 7.x, IE 8.x, Firefox 3.5.x, Safari 4.x, Opera 10.x, Chrome 3.x

It uses version Jquery 1.7.2 and Jquery UI 1.8.18

Also use plugin `http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/jquery.searchabledropdown.js`

You can check the running version on JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/JWyRZ/

Answer (score 0):

You always can use jquery-browser-plugin plugin from https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin. It adds the functionality missed by upgrade to 1.9. Just make sure you load jquery first and jquery-browser plugin afterwards.